# C# 3d model viewer

Tags: c#, 3d

What is the best thing to use in C# that you can view a 3D model in? I need to change the texture of the model too. I looked at XNA but I cant find the download link.

Comment: Oh, what format is the model in? It all depends on this crucial piece of information.

Comment: @Orangelight questions like these tend to be considered too broad/opinionated/subjective for SO.  Please read the SO question guidelines :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a WPF 3d ViewPort

There is an amazing utility called HelixToolkit which you can find here:
https://github.com/helix-toolkit

The Helix toolkit adds a large amount of extended options for 3D rendering in a WPF enviroment.

Also you can use SlimDX which is also a managed 3D library based on DirectX. which you can find here:
http://slimdx.org/

EDIT::

Some information on importing 3ds models into WPF 3d [http://www.codegod.com/render-3ds-3d-models-with-wpf-and-xaml-AID433.aspx (archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20140223195246/http://www.codegod.com:80/render-3ds-3d-models-with-wpf-and-xaml-AID433.aspx)

Comment: The toolkit really is just an extension. I would focus on tutorials on WPF 3D Viewports. Depending on what you would like to do in terms of animation and interaction it is a fairly simple proceudre. Here is a pretty good tut: http://www.kindohm.com/technical/WPF3DTutorial.htm

Comment: I need to import a model in to the program how can I achieve this in Helix 3D Toolkit?

Comment: Ok what kind of model is it so I can give you the most concise answer.

Comment: Check the answer for a tuorial

Comment: Codeplex is shutting down, so I am posting the repository's new location. 
https://github.com/helix-toolkit